# dotMemory profiling huge memory difference between iisexpress & WebDev

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis-express, memory-profiling

I'm trying to get a handle on memory usage of my ASP.NET MVC4 / EF5 web application through dotMemory profiling. I'm still confused by what I see, but one thing that concerns me is the large difference in memory between running a profile on IISExpress and WebDev.

At start up, IISExpress shows (* Actually this jumped each time I killed the process and started up the profiler again):

- Total: 352.3 MB
- Heap Gen 0: 242.7 MB
- Heap Gen 1: 3.1 KB
- Heap Gen 2: 31.5 MB

Whereas WebDev:

- Total: 180 MB
- Heap Gen 0: 3 MB
- Heap Gen 1: 148.2 KB
- Heap Gen 2: 24.6 MB

This application is hosted on IIS 7.5 so which should I trust? And why does my managed memory go down after a snapshot? This is especially true with IISExpress.

Also I'm having a hard time finding what are real issues I can impact. Things tend to boil down to EF or AutoMapper and I don't see how I can avoid iterator allocation in entity linq queries and CreateMaps, etc. (http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/07/24/unusual-ways-of-boosting-up-app-performance-lambdas-and-linqs/)

What am I not seeing?

**Edit**

Memory Traffic snapshot -- String is the largest consumer
[image: JScript]

Lots of byte allocated from using AutoMapper's CreateMap -- any possible remedy?
[image: AutoMapper]

Comment: 7mln objects is quite huge traffic. For what time period this traffic is produced?
Unfortunately I can't help you with EF and AutoMapper, I'm not enough familiar with them, I can only help you with interpreting profiling results.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!  This is in my test environment when I load the search page which has a bunch of dropdown filters (all queries from the db) and loads the first 50 items, pagination, with count of all items which could be in the thousands.  I have UoW and repository pattern and used to use uow to grab the data, but moved to separate using dbcontext to enable projection and disable lazy-loading, validate on save, and auto tracking of the queries. This was before I got dotMemory and I'm wondering if all those lists in memory just shifted my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Heap Gen 0: 242.7 MB

This is a specific thing of IIS to have a very huge Gen 0 heaps

> And why does my managed memory go down after a snapshot? This is especially true with IISExpress.

dotMemory forces garbage collecting on getting snapshot (this is how MS profiling API works)

> Also I'm having a hard time finding what are real issues I can impact.

I would recommend to check if a picture of the memory consumption correlates with a picture "in your head". Check top 5-10 types which objects consumes the greatest amount of the memory. Look at top objects exclusively retains memory. Check an app on memory leaks - all objects are released after a particular activity finishes.
If you don't see any very unusual, maybe you do not have to do anything.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to solve my app's performance issue without knowing what the real issue is because we have not been able to receive any data from the server admins. Our current theory is it uses too much memory causing near 100% CPU usage. The admins throttled the app to 30% and we tried reducing EF's memory usage (disabled tracking, lazy loading, validate on save for reads, reduce calls to db, etc), but we see hanging worker process requests daily and now with dotMemory, I'm wondering if all the ToList() to force queries before the context is lost introduced other memory concerns.

Comment: If you suspect that your app slows down because of GC takes too much time, you may look at memory traffic produced by the app. https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/help/Analyzing_Traffic.html
If the app just consumes all available memory and slows down because of swapping, look at top memory consumers as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Yes I am trying to follow your suggestions, but a lot of this is still new to me.  I've added screenshots to highlight some of my confusion over what I can and can't impact. High allocation has been found with AutoMapper, but so far the only thing I can see that I can track down and change is avoid DisplayFor razor template helpers where possible to reduce Dictionary resizing (http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/07/10/unusual-ways-of-boosting-up-app-performance-boxing-and-collections/)